# CSS Rule Application Methods - Attribute Wildcard vs Listing Every Class

Tags: css

I'll borrow this declaration in Bootstrap CSS as an example:

```
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
    float: left;
}
```

I've noticed this pattern across other frameworks as well. I think this could more easily be written as:

```
[class*='col-xs-'] {
    float: left;
}
```

When trying to apply a rule to a set of classes, are there any benefits to writing out every single class rather than using the attribute wildcard method? In such situations, I prefer to use the latter in my work, but I've noticed that quite a few CSS libraries write out every class.

Comment: I believe in this specific situation, because they use col-xs- in other classes (col-xs-offset-), the wildcards would cause conflicts.

Comment: Two issues with later approach: (i) the substring matching selector `*=` causes unintentional matching e.g. `[class*=col-xs-]` matches `xxcol-xs-xx`; whereas `|=` and `~=` have limitations (ii) attribute selector has less specifity than class selector so `.foo{float: right;}` beats `[class*=col-xs-]{float: left}` **even when specified in that order**. Lastly, no one actually types those lengthy rules as the one in first example. These rules are *generated* via CSS pre-processors.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute wildcard is more expensive for the browser to interpret than writing out the classes. In most cases the libraries you are mentioning are not writing out these classes by hand but using a preprocessor like sass or less to pro-grammatically create all the possible options.

http://sass-lang.com/
http://lesscss.org/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS

Also, `*=` is a CSS3 feature so it's better to use explicit names where possible to increase compatability.

Comment: @SalmanA , Why not worry about it? In this case its something can be easily avoided so why make the browser do extra work.

Comment: @SalmanA Is that because performance gains are negligible or because such claims are unfounded?

Comment: @BillPull In your MDN link, I don't see any information that is relevant to the performance of attribute or attribute wildcard selectors.

Comment: @WalterRoman I previously had this link https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-selectors-that-look-like-regular-expressions from css lint but took it off in case someone had evidence against it since CSSLint is pretty opinionated. But my assumption is evaluating regex against the DOM is slower than a class. Although one instance is probably negligible.

Comment: @BillPull Thanks for that. Unfortunately, it looks as though their link on the performance costs of certain attribute selectors is dead.

Comment: Oops well I would imagine that if you were to create an entire framework the size of Bootstrap out of regex selectors the performance could be noticeable. I think what @SalmanA is getting at is that it is really up to the browser vendors to optimize the selector performance not you.